# TPM tss2 certificate signing request sign by CA

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, openssl, x.509, tpm

I am trying to sign certificate by CA which generated by CA. But I am facing below error code while singing.

Generate certificate:

```
# tpm2tss-genkey -a rsa -s 2048 mykey
# openssl req -new -engine tpm2tss -key mykey -keyform engine -out tpm.csr
```

ERROR Sign:

```
openssl ca -batch -config ca.conf -notext -in device.csr -out device.crt 
Using configuration from ca.conf
Check that the request matches the signature
Signature did not match the certificate request
404741C1CE7F0000:error:02000068:rsa routines:ossl_rsa_verify:bad signature:../crypto/rsa/rsa_sign.c:430:
404741C1CE7F0000:error:1C880004:Provider routines:rsa_verify:RSA lib:../providers/implementations/signature/rsa_sig.c:774:
404741C1CE7F0000:error:06880006:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify_ctx:EVP lib:../crypto/asn1/a_verify.c:217:
```

File contents:
cat mykey

```
-----BEGIN TSS2 PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END TSS2 PRIVATE KEY-----


-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----


openssl req -noout -text -in device.csr 
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Subject: C = AU, ST = Berlin, L = i2g, O = i2gdev, OU = i2g, CN = device
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:c9:b8:02:7b:c3:56:b3:c5:44:f3:e7:6c:2b:ed:
                    ec:cf:10:f0:7a:c4:52:f2:c4:58:08:c9:7c:f3:1d:
                    3c:b7:2c:fe:81:1d:2d:53:4e:9b:69:09:25:64:36:
                    7e:83:d3:7f:96:c4:1f:0b:d6:a8:16:63:d7:8e:f4:
                    14:14:77:26:ac:af:ea:db:c7:55:8a:4e:e5:1f:87:
                    a8:2b:c0:0e:c9:52:5d:b6:49:85:de:18:46:59:90:
                    3b:75:ae:1f:6a:42:d3:90:ab:ce:b2:55:56:8c:d7:
                    e3:a9:90:f8:19:c1:74:cc:27:19:0a:87:33:5a:4a:
                    72:14:8e:49:21:7c:ec:b0:9c:51:15:7a:4a:2e:c6:
                    3d:94:fb:d7:d6:76:bf:23:b2:50:41:da:f5:70:52:
                    13:75:6d:e4:2a:b5:ee:14:4f:b3:2c:88:db:05:f9:
                    a2:6f:0d:a8:21:95:78:db:1e:99:21:13:4e:56:35:
                    2a:1c:c1:e2:2e:c1:4b:25:5a:ff:e1:61:99:59:ca:
                    79:87:06:3f:e3:e9:63:38:cf:4e:67:31:1e:d4:33:
                    10:38:9a:1b:5c:65:ea:d9:a0:ff:b8:40:61:90:61:
                    09:60:77:f6:7b:c6:19:3f:b8:e3:bd:95:92:42:41:
                    18:c4:4e:04:ba:25:0f:20:96:d8:15:ca:0b:7d:2f:
                    49:eb
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        Attributes:
            (none)
            Requested Extensions:
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Value:
        a2:ec:b3:71:76:1c:65:13:57:d8:32:43:2f:11:b7:05:91:a5:
        ac:ae:f7:dd:ed:d6:28:56:0f:4f:46:aa:72:5b:01:32:2e:b1:
        4a:b9:98:a4:d7:67:5d:f4:8f:63:04:34:3f:60:b9:d4:87:e9:
        4a:fd:f3:d0:6e:3c:d5:c8:89:f0:f3:e8:2f:84:6a:10:7e:b4:
        19:09:45:79:fe:ea:cd:bb:3a:e5:75:eb:e7:53:dc:57:06:52:
        61:77:c7:b6:6b:cb:c8:2c:f3:a0:b1:58:a9:0b:7a:77:3c:c8:
        98:88:ce:c2:7f:56:ec:03:b3:0b:1d:81:0b:6d:84:b2:c6:3a:
        eb:6b:4a:f2:f8:5f:fc:c8:7a:37:b3:06:e8:87:32:9f:53:d0:
        34:d0:fb:e9:5a:3a:19:bf:f0:ea:23:39:f9:51:09:21:1d:8c:
        1c:10:a0:b6:c9:85:b0:9b:41:1f:69:bc:b5:62:c2:b4:62:39:
        82:47:3f:0a:f6:dc:2c:0e:9b:1a:b2:f7:5a:51:32:7b:9f:f1:
        03:7a:99:97:ec:06:fb:3c:c8:77:e7:8f:be:2d:32:cf:27:fa:
        01:30:63:cf:06:9c:db:4a:07:de:b5:d1:0d:52:7b:62:e0:2b:
        05:8b:d6:24:11:11:ae:7b:c8:79:ba:ba:29:2d:d7:61:a2:cb:
        5d:a6:b4:d4
```